# Set function integal

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

We have a vector $y$ ($\sum_i y_i=1$). Define $S(r) = \{i, y_i\geq r \}$. Here is an integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} |S(r)| dr=\sum_i y_i$. I don't know why the integral is correct. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Consider the one dimensional case first.

Comment: @deinst For one dimensional case, we have $y=1$ and $\int_0^\infty |S(r)|dr = \int_0^1 1 dr = 1 = y$. It is correct. But how to derive the multi-dimensional one.

Comment: The multidimensional case is just the sum of one dimensional cases $|S(r)|$ just counts the number of elements in $y$ less than $r$.

Comment: @deinst I still don't get it. Can you mathematically explain in detail:)

Comment: Consider the function $f_i(r)=[y_i\ge r]$ that is 1 if $y_i\ge r$ and 0 otherwise.  Now $|S(r)=\sum y_i(r)|$.  It is just the cardinality of the set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|S(r)|$ is the number of $y$ not less than $r$, so $|S(r)|=\sum_{i=1}^n I_{\{y_i \geq r\}}$, here $I_{\{y_i \geq r\}}=1 $ if $y_i \geq r$, $$\int_0^\infty |S(r)|dr=\int_0^\infty\sum_{i=1}^n I_{\{y_i \geq r\}} dr=\sum_{i=1}^n\int_0^\infty I_{\{y_i \geq r\}} dr=\sum_{i=1}^n y_i =1.$$